# How can I open the file location of a running process?

Tags: macos, terminal

I can `ps -x` to get a list then `grep` the name then manually type in the process number to `lsof -p` to list the processes open file locations and get the `cwd` of the process ... whew! all this manual work. is there a way to say "go to process location" ?

Comment: cwd is not necessarily the process location - What exactly are you after? Most Apps will start with current directory of /

Answer (score 1):

Not aware of such a function, yet that doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

However, I'm guessing you could simply program it into bashrc? It shouldn't be too hard to make a manual command for this..

For example by adding something like this function to your .bashrc:

```
function showp() {
    pid=$(ps -x | grep -i $1 | awk '{print $1}' | head -1)
    dir=$(lsof -p $pid | grep cwd | awk '{print $9}')
    cd $dir
    echo "Now arrived here: " $(pwd) 
}
```

Then (after sourcing bashrc of course) simply type (for example): `showp safari` and it will output:

```
Now arrived here:  /
```